# os.rename fails to rename files for a certain directory

Tags: python

This is my first time using stack overflow so sorry if i make a mistake.

When trying to run this code it will execute fine and give me my properly renamed files.

```
import os
a = 0
name_target = raw_input("input the prefix of the files you want enumerated")
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith(name_target):
        a = int(a) + 1
        a = str(a)
        no = filename.__len__() - 4
        os.rename(filename, filename[:no] + a + '.txt')
```

Now this is fine as long as the script exists in the same folder as the files are. But I want to be able to use this script with files which are not in the same folder.

I have found that `os.listdir('\some\folder\elsewhere')` works fine for other directories but when it comes to renaming them with`os.rename` the code breaks giving me the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 244, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\guy\Desktop\otherfolder\renaming_script.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, filename[:no] + a + '.txt')
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`
```

I have no idea what is wrong here please help me.

Comment: For the rename, you also have to provide the full path and not just the filename

Comment: @andi: please inform users of the improper windows tag instead of just editing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for other directories, you are getting the directory contents properly but when you try and rename the contents simply by using filenames, the program in fact looks it its own directory, and being unable to find the file, throws an error. Instead you should do something as follows:

`os.rename('\some\folder\elsewhere\filename.txt', '\some\folder\elsewhere\filename2.txt')`

Or, you can also do the following:

```
directory = '\some\folder\elsewhere'
os.rename(os.path.join(directory, 'filename.txt'), os.path.join(directory, 'filename2.txt'))
```

Or, you can also change your working directory as follows:

```
os.chdir('\some\folder\elsewhere')
```

An then simply call the `os.rename` method as if you are in the desired directory
    os.rename('filename.txt', 'filenam2.txt')

Comment: Thanks the second solution you gave me seemed to work even with my enumeration

Answer (score 0):

If you use `os.listdir(path)`, you also have to provide the path in the rename: `os.rename(path+filename,path+new_name)`.

Other option is to use `os.chdir(desired_path)`. With this, your `os.rename` is fine.