# Deleting empty folders and renaming

Tags: python, directory-structure

I have folders whose names are just increasing integers: The folders are stored in 'dirName' 
[image]

Some folders are empty (like folder 5) and I would like to delete them. After the deletion I would like to rename the remaining folders such that there is no gap between the numbers. (i.e. 1,2,4,6 after deletion, and 1,2,3 (4->3), 4 (6->4) after renaming).

How could I do this with python3?

EDIT: 
To delete a file or folder: [Delete a file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/delete-a-file-or-folder)

My Code:

```
# Remove empty folders
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
for dirname in dirnames:
    try:  # works if directory is empty
        os.rmdir(dirpath + "\\" + dirname)
    except:
        pass
# Rename
iteration = 1
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        shutil.move(dirpath + "\\" + dirname, dirpath + "\\" + str(iteration))
        iteration += 1
```

...it works but it seems rather bulky... 
//another piece of code

```
# Remove empty folders
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        try:  # works if directory is empty
            os.rmdir(dirpath + "\\" + dirname)
        except:
            pass
    # Rename
    iteration = 1
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
        if dirpath!=dirname:
            os.rename(dirpath,str(iteration))
        iteration += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/delete-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry, yes, here you go

Comment: it doesn't show in your code anywhere that you check if a folder is empty or not

Comment: @aws_apprentice This is done by os.rmdir -> will only delete if empty

Comment: Do you always have 2 digits for the folder names, or might these be longer?

Comment: @ggorlen For now only two digits I doubt that it will be longer anytime soon

Comment: @henry You must typechange the name in line os.rename to str.

Comment: @nitangle I thought that I did just that "str(iteration)" ?

Comment: yes..I just saw after writing that. My bad:)

Comment: @henry I just tried scripting myself and I think you do not need to use shitutils.move method. Just os.rename worked for me.

Comment: @nitangle Did somehow not work for me, so I will stick with shitutils.move for now

Comment: @henry Can you specify the error?

Comment: @nitangle Its detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630841/os-rename-fails-to-rename-files-for-a-certain-directory

Comment: @henry Ok I understand. I think this should be simple to resolve. Sorry I forgot to mention earlier. When it iterates over the director the first element is that directory itself. So you must skip that directory. Using a simple if worked for me. Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: @nitangle Could you please post your code as an answer, such that I can better understand ? Thanks

Comment: @henry I have added another code version. Hope it helps.

Comment: @nitangle I tried it but I get a PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Comment: @henry Take a look at this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857779/why-os-rename-sometimes-returns-error-access-is-denied-python)